# How to display User in ListView in Fragment from Firebase?

Tags: android, listview, firebase-realtime-database, android-arrayadapter

I have an app with user login, there is basic data such as Name, email,Age etc. but i want to display only 2 data for each user in a list view. Im pretty much a beginner in using ListView so i dont know where to start. Especially when Im using Fragment:

My code here:

```
     @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }

    tutorList = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tutorListView);

    tutorArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    tutorAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tutorArrayList);

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().getRoot();


    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Tutees").child(userID);




        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

I'm also get confused which one to put in onCreate() method or onCreateView() method since im using fragment.

here's my json Structure in firebase:

```
       "Users" : {
"Tutors" : {

  "daBTEVRQagX7XbwPbXE5X1l3tg62" : {
    "Age" : "22",
    "District" : "miami",
    "Email" : "tutor@gmail.com",
    "Name" : "Ainul",
    "Qualification" : "hnd",
    "profileImageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tutorpal-1.appspot.com/o/profileImageUrl%2FdaBTEVRQagX7XbwPbXE5X1l3tg62?alt=media&token=a81ccf26-091d-4001-aa23-04665ad27173"
  },
  "glk3Wi1lZZOQkt2UNsGit02DEym2" : {
    "profileImageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tutorpal-1.appspot.com/o/profileImageUrl%2Fglk3Wi1lZZOQkt2UNsGit02DEym2?alt=media&token=61192989-93c8-4c55-bca0-9d2b3a6a78fe"
  },
  "yE6ALyKEjVOoNLZcHEvHmeYkqON2" : {
    "FullName" : "hai im ainul ",
    "UserName" : "ainul",
    "profileImageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tutorpal-1.appspot.com/o/profileImageUrl%2FyE6ALyKEjVOoNLZcHEvHmeYkqON2?alt=media&token=aa63a6f2-0154-4c27-b7ba-d8de89ee64bc"
  }
}
```

}

basically i want to access Users-Tutors-Users-all their information

I also want the listview to be set as onclicklistener so whenever user click a user, it will bring to another activity which is the profileActivity of the user. I already have the profileactivity view set but dont know how to do this from a listView to ProfileActivity

Comment: Fragment does not matter. You need an Adapter class added to the Listview to display anything

Answer (score 1):

First, I suggest you read about [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/README.md) library and try to [get examples working](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md)

Basically, you're missing a `ListView.setAdapter`

If you want to have click events, `adapter.setOnItemClickListener`

> I'm also get confused which one to put in onCreate() method or onCreateView() method since im using fragment.

Ideally, only onCreateView returns the inflated View. **onViewCreated** is where you use findViewById for a Fragment. *You cannot call getView from onCreate*